# DirSync & Office 365 - how I can sync users?

Tags: active-directory, office365, windows-server-2012

Couple days ago I have turn-on DirSync on Office365 and AD. Unfortunately All users, that was not create on Office 365 account has been created and sync with domain.

I work on **Windows Server 2012**

I have get information like that:

> [UserPrincipalName user@domain.com;WindowsLiveNetId System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Byte];]

The solution for this problem is probably here:

[Problem solution](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2647098)
or
[Microsoft Solution #1](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852469.aspx#bkmk_adcleanup)

But how I can sync this users without delete them? **I can't lose their data and e-mails.** Have you know any solution for that?

Update description:

> I will try to describe my problem better than at the begging.
>   I have AD in my company :) and we use Office 365 - until couple days ago we turn on DirSync. Unfortunately there is some serious problem. Only users that have not been created in Office 365 are created by AD and fully Sync. Users who has been created in Office 365 before turn on DirSync has not been sync.
>   I have try to change UPN -> AD create new user.
>   I try to use MOSDAL and Office 365 Deployment Readiness Tool - with no effects.
>   I don't have any idea to resolve this problem. Have you any solution, instruction, advice?

Best regards.

Tanks for any info!

Comment: You should call Office 365 support, it's free and it's the only way you'll get a supported answer.

Answer (score 0):

dirsync in one-way synchronisation. Objects created in Office 365 cant be synchronised with your on-premise AD. After dirsync activation your AD becomes "source of authority".